# DIV won't align to center

Tags: html, css, alignment

I have problem with centering div element. I tried with marings (margin: o auto) and with left/right CSS atributes (left: 50%, right: 50%) but result was wrong. Can someone tell me where's the problem?

EDIT:

I am using JavaScript to fill content of "boxcard" div. Problem is that content of "boxcard" div is not aligned to center (it's aligned to left). I am using JavaScript code (added below) to fill DIV's content.

This is what I have:

[image]

EDIT 2:

Here is jsfiddle : [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s7w3q/)

CSS:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
body {
    font: 18px Verdana;
    color: #FFF;
  background: #CCC;
}
#picbox {
    margin: 0px auto;
    width: auto;
}
#boxcard {
    z-index: 1;
        margin: 0px auto;
    width: auto;
}
#boxcard div{
    float: left;
    width: 100;
    height: 120;
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 4px solid #EE872A;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
  background: #B1B1B1;
    z-index: 2;
}
#boxcard > div:nth-child(6n+1) {
    clear: both;
}
#boxcard div img {
    display: none;
    border-radius: 10px;
    z-index: 3;
}
#boxbuttons {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 20px;
    display: block;
}
#boxbuttons .button {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    background: #EE872A;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    margin: 5px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#boxbuttons .button:hover {
    background: #999;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="picbox">
  <span id="boxbuttons">
    <span class="button" id="rezz">
         Result
      <span id="counter">0</span>
    </span>
    <span class="button" id="ttime"></span>
    <span class="button">
      <a onclick="ResetGame();">Reset</a>
    </span> 
  </span>
  <div id="boxcard" align="center"></div>
</div>
```

This is JS Code that creates DIV blocks (i.e. Cards)

```
function ShuffleImages() {
    var ImgAll = $(Source).children();
    var ImgThis = $(Source + " div:first-child");
    var ImgArr = new Array();

    for (var i = 0; i < ImgAll.length; i++) {
        ImgArr[i] = $("#" + ImgThis.attr("id") + " img").attr("src");
        ImgThis = ImgThis.next();
    }

        ImgThis = $(Source + " div:first-child");

    for (var z = 0; z < ImgAll.length; z++) {
    var RandomNumber = RandomFunction(0, ImgArr.length - 1);

        $("#" + ImgThis.attr("id") + " img").attr("src", ImgArr[RandomNumber]);
        ImgArr.splice(RandomNumber, 1);
        ImgThis = ImgThis.next();
    }
}

    $(function() {

for (var y = 1; y < 3 ; y++) {
    $.each(ImgSource, function(i, val) {
        $(Source).append("<div id=card" + y + i + "><img src=" + val + " />");
    });
}
    $(Source + " div").click(OpenCard);
    ShuffleImages();
});
```

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit? http://jsfiddle.net/K5Txb/ seems to show center-aligned items.

Comment: exactly nothing wrong here on my side

Comment: I added ScreenShot of my result @MuhammadUmer

Comment: please provide with the demo, the boxes don't appear in jsfiddle

Comment: @user3739658 I updated my question with jsfiddle link

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add `display: table`. This is how you center an element with a undefined width

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/s7w3q/2/

```
#boxcard {
    z-index: 1;
    display: table;
    margin: 0px auto;
    width: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#boxcard div{
    width: 100px;
    display:inline-block;
    height: 120px;
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 4px solid #EE872A;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    background: #B1B1B1;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

You were using `float:left;` on `#boxcard div` even when you were using `align"center" with`HTML`

Also you needed to use `px` after `height` and `width`

Comment: Problem with your code is that I have one card in row insted of six @user3739658

Comment: The fact that you had px not listed might have caused problems in some browsers so it is better to have it

Answer (score 0):

another way to do this would be more efficient. As it'd Remove the need to separately align `boxbuttons`.

```
#boxcard {
    display: inline-block;
...
}
....
#picbox {
    text-align: center;
...
}
```